# How to replace empty spaces that come from excel in android using apache-poi?

Tags: java, android, regex, excel, apache-poi

I have an app that imports an excel but the excel in question has black spaces in some of the cells, when I receive it puts those blank spaces in my database. I want to prevent that to happen, i tried to use regex and replace(" ","") and nothing work. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
File file = new File(inFileName);
            Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

            int rowCtr = 34;
            Row myRow = sheet.getRow(rowCtr++);
            while (myRow != null) {
                Cell nif = myRow.getCell(0);
                Cell marcaexploracao = myRow.getCell(1);
                Cell numerochip = myRow.getCell(2);
                Cell marcaauricular = myRow.getCell(3);
                Cell datanascimento = myRow.getCell(4);

//problem I mentioned is is in chipnumber only
                bd.addAnimais(chipnumber.ToString().replaceFirst("/[^0-9]/","-"),marcaexploracao.toString(),marcaauricular.toString(),datanascimento.toString(),nif.toString(),0,"","","","",0);
                myRow = sheet.getRow(rowCtr++);
            }



        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the blank spaces are " " and not some other white space character such as "\t"?

Comment: Excel is spreadsheet software. One does not import an Excel. One imports an Excel spreadsheet. Or they simply import a spreadsheet. Excel can actually export\import many different formats. You also seem to have variables in multiple languages. I believe `numerochip` is supposed to be `chipnumber` (or vice-versa), for example.

Comment: I dont know, how can I discover that, is there a way?

Comment: yes is chipnumber

Comment: I need a way to find out wish character is the cause of this whitespace